# How best to structure private methods in my Node.JS AWS Lambda function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

Say I have the following code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('Event', event);
  if (event.eventType === 'JOB') {
      await handleJobCompletionEvent(event);
  } else if (event.eventType == 'JOB_EXECUTION') {
      await handleJobExecutionEvent(event);
  } else {
      console.error('Invalid event type');
  }
};

// function delcarations
```

How would I best declare the referenced functions so that I can reference said methods inside the handler as well as other methods?

Comment: Just put them literally anywhere in the same script. If you want to use them across several modules, put them in a module, export them and `require()` them wherever needed.

Comment: @ChrisG Does hoisting and not play a role here? I feel like there is a way to declare them such that they would be undefined when I call them in the handler?

Comment: Only if you put them inside other functions. Why don't you just give it a try?